# Translucent menu bar option is simply gone after system reboot / freeze (Mac OS X Lion)

Tags: macos, settings, menu-bar

I'm on Mac OS X Lion 10.7.2. I just had one of the infamous 'blue screens' when the MBP freezes (known for the early 2011 models).

After my system booted up again, my menu bar isn't translucent anymore (as it was before), and also, even the option to activate it (as described in http://www.mactrast.com/2011/10/mac-tip-translucent-menu-bar-in-mac-os-x-lion/) is simply gone from my settings screen.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did another reboot and the menu bar is back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing this problem, although I'm not experiencing any system freezes. Another workaround is simply to uncheck and then recheck "Translucent menu bar" in System Preferences > Desktop & Screen Saver.

Comment: I tried that, but didn't work for me, at least not in combination with the system freeze. Only hard reboot worked ok in my case.